# Some apps seem to sleep while the screensaver runs. How to prevent this in Monterey 12.6.5 with 2014 Mac Mini?

Tags: applications, sleep-wake, mac-mini, monterey, screensaver

This question is ***not*** about keeping the Mac itself from going to sleep... I got that part (settings > energy saver > power > check "prevent your mac from automatically sleeping...").  When time is up, the screen saver comes on & stays on, and I enter my password to get back to the desktop, but the computer never sleeps & the screensaver never stops running... so far so good.

What I have are three apps that run from Xcode, each of which accomplishes a task every 15 seconds -- the first one checks for info on a server, the second one processes anything the first one downloaded and puts the result on disk where the third one can send out notifications.  When the screensaver is not running, the apps run every 15 seconds as intended, and it's under a minute round trip from an external app putting info on the server, until the reply comes back. So far, so good.

BUT... ***when the screen saver is running***, the apps no longer run on their 15 second schedule. The loops seem to happen between 2 and 5 minutes apart, meaning that the round-trip can now take 10+ minutes. If I login after stopping the screensaver, then everything runs normally again (i.e. all 3 apps are back to their every-15-second loops -- they didn't terminate along the way). But when the machine is running unattended, it's like the apps snooze in some way, only running their loops sometimes.

Hardware: all of the above is on a Late 2014 Mac Mini with Monterey 12.6.5. Strangely, on my 2018 MacMini running Ventura 13.1, it matters not if the screensaver is running -- the apps perform on their 15 second cycle, and the roundtrip is under a minute regardless. So there seems to be something about the older hardware and/or OS that makes the apps less responsive.

Is there any setting that prevents the apps from running on their schedule when the screen saver is running? Is there any way to keep the apps themselves from going lazy when I'm not around to watch them?

Comment: What happens if you run them directly not using Xcode?

Comment: @mmmmmm  Same behavior, no improvement.